# How to setup a JavaScript ip logger to work with EmailJS?

Tags: javascript, html, ip

I have been trying to get a JavaScript code to work with EmailJS but couldn’t find out how to do it. The code I’ve been trying to get to work:

```
<script>
function getIP(json) {  
   alert("My public IP address is: " + json.ip);
}
</script>
<script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>`
```

It’s HTML and I’m trying to put it on a Weebly website. I’m new to html coding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's working for me? Is it in a `.html` file?

Comment: This HTML code works for me. It looks like the JavaScript code is blocked by Weebly (e.g. cross domain issue). Is there any error message in browser console?